# I am having this problem in react-radux. The error is An immer producer returned a new value

Tags: reactjs

I want to update my state. So I copy the original state into a new variable and then update the new variable with a new value. Then reassign the new variable to the original state and I get this error
My recordSlice.js

```
  showSelectMovieForEdit: function(state,action){
            let newArray = [...state.value];
            for(let i =0; i< state.value.length;i++){
               if(state.value[i].id===action.payload)
                {
                  newArray[i].displayOneMovie=true;
                }
                else {
                  newArray[i].displayOneMovie=false;
                }
            }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    value: newArray
                }
        },
```

The error is Uncaught Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft. Can you also tell me another way of updating the state
My initial state

```
export const recordSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'Record Slice',
    initialState: {
        value: [
            { "id": 1,"movie name" : "Ticket to Paradise","display":"true","description":"Academy Award® winners George Clooney and Julia Roberts reunite on the big screen as exes who find themselves on a shared mission to stop their lovestruck daughter from making the same mistake they once made","genre" :"Comedy", "lead actor": ["George Clooney", "Julia Roberts"],"rating":5,"displayOneMovie":false,"language":"english"},
            { "id": 2, "movie name": "Black Panter","display":true,"description":"Queen Ramonda (Angela Bassett), Shuri (Letitia Wright), M’Baku (Winston Duke), Okoye (Danai Gurira) and the Dora Milaje (including Florence Kasumba), fight to protect their nation from intervening world powers in the wake of King T’Challa’s death.","genre":"Action","lead actor":["Angela Bassett","Letitia Wright"],"rating":6,"displayOneMovie":false,"language":"english"},
            { "id":3, "movie name": "Smile","display":true,"description":"After witnessing a bizarre, traumatic incident involving a patient, Dr. Rose Cotter (Sosie Bacon) starts experiencing frightening occurrences that she can't explain.","genre":"Drama","lead actor":["Sosie Bacon","Jessie T. Usher"],"rating":6,"displayOneMovie":false,"language":"english"},
            {"id":4,"movie name":"Come Back Home","display":true,"description":"In the cold winter, a group of Shenzhen tourist families take a trip to the northeast Changbai Mountain. It was originally intended to be a happy and harmonious holiday, but due to the negligence of his father, an 8-year-old boy is unfortunately lost.","genre":"Mistery","lead actor":["Donnie Yen", "Han Xue"],"rating":6,"displayOneMovie":false,"language":"mandarian"},
            {"id":5,"movie name":"Ajoomma","display":true,"description":"Auntie (Hong Huifang), is a middle-aged Singaporean woman who has dedicated the best years of her life to caring for her family. Now widowed with her grown up son, Sam (Shane Pow) about to fly the roost, Auntie is left to contend with a whole new identity beyond her roles of daughter, wife, and mother.","genre":"Drama","lead actor":["Hong Huifang", "Jung Dong-Hwan"],"rating":4,"displayOneMovie":false,"language":"mandarian"}
        ], // No records initially
    },
```

Hope someone can provide me an answer.

Comment: I am trying to choose a movie for edit so the id is pass to the showSelectMovieForEdit

Comment: I am trying to choose a movie for edit so the id is pass to the showSelectMovieFEdit. How am I going to update the state.value.id that I have change to the initial data